# how to set custom Extentions in html file type

Tags: html, file-upload

I need to set only specific file extentions for html file field.

```
 <input type="file" id="image1" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" />
```

From above code it is working well, but it also display All type and other extentions

But i want to disable or not display in extention list.

Can you please help me as how can i fix this issue

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and you wouldn't want to, either.

You should **always** ensure the data a user uploads is in a desired format on the server side. Specifying file extensions on the client side is great as it lets users know what files they should be uploading, but in reality there's nothing to stop someone changing the name and extension of their "scaryvirus.exe" file to something which appears innocent like "cutekitten.png". You should never trust user input.

From the [`input[type="file"]` section of the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#file-upload-state-%28type=file%29):

> Extensions tend to be ambiguous (e.g. there are an untold number of formats that use the ".dat" extension, and users can typically quite easily rename their files to have a ".doc" extension even if they are not Microsoft Word documents), and MIME types tend to be unreliable (e.g. many formats have no formally registered types, and many formats are in practice labeled using a number of different MIME types). Authors are reminded that, as usual, data received from a client should be treated with caution, as it may not be in an expected format even if the user is not hostile and the user agent fully obeyed the accept attribute's requirements.

The specification doesn't define the ability to remove "All Files" or whichever other options may be present in a user agent's file upload UI. That said, not all user agents will support the `accept` property, either.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to write the extensions in the accept attribute. Instead, you should use the MIME type:

```
<input type="file" id="image1" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png" />
```

Even then, you're probably going to get "All files" in the dialog. That's just the way things are - if you really care about the extension, you're going to have to check on the server. Of course, in practice, you'd probably want to check the *contents* rather than the extension (which can be changed at will).

Comment: That's not true. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file). You can specify file types or MIME types or both.

Comment: I know this thing, but i also want to disable "All Datatype" in dialog open portion. i want to display my custom extention.

Comment: @harshboss: Yeah, sorry, you're stuck. You could validate the file name in javascript, though - on your submit button, check the filename on the input, and say you can only upload *.wtv.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: That is only true for HTML 5, though. Earlier standards only allow MIME types.